# WordPress - How do I approve posts before they are allowed to be posted?

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I'm currently working with a WordPress site and the owner wants the posts that are created by other members to be sent to his email with a way of approving the post before it's actually made public and posted.

I'm pretty new in general to web design and even newer to WordPress. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I used to run a large blog site which required a workflow for approvals and QA of posts. We customized the Edit Flow plugin, which allows for stages for a post. You can find the plugin here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/edit-flow/.

In our case, I used Draft, Pending Editing, In Editing, For Approval, Approved, Staged, and Ready. Only when it was set to Ready would the publish button appear (this is one of the edits we made to the plugin, and donated back. Not sure if it is in the current version or not.) Only admins would be able to change the stage of the post, so this way no one was able to publish except admins.

Answer (score -1):

So if you just want to approve the posts you can do it in the admin interface. The Request URL should be: /wp-login.php . There is one the left side a menu with a section 'posts'. ( You can approve the posts here )

I hope it is useful.